# Sorting Struct on multiple attributes

Tags: ruby, sorting, struct

I have struct

```
[#<struct Page page="P3", value=64, query="Q1">, 
 #<struct Page page="P2", value=64, query="Q1">, 
 #<struct Page page="P1", value=48,    
 query="Q1">]
```

When I sort it by value it gets (decreasing order)

```
[#<struct Page page="P3", value=64, query="Q1">, #<struct Page page="P2", value=64, query="Q1">, #<struct Page page="P1", value=48, query="Q1">]
```

Now I want output

```
[#<struct Page page="P2", value=64, query="Q1">, #<struct Page page="P3", value=64, query="Q1">, #<struct Page page="P1", value=48, query="Q1">]
```

Now I want the struct to be sorted by page attribute (with smallest first).

Comment: Have you tried `sort_by`? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You want to sort your array by which criteria exactly?

Comment: @undur_gongor OP wanted to sort it descending order. as I am looking into the output - *Now i want output* part.

Comment: @OMG: Yes, read that. But then, take a look at the title.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it be simply:

```
x.sort_by(&:page)
```

If you want to sort by several attributes, you can do it like:

```
x.sort_by{ | e | [e.page, e.value] }
```

or

```
x.sort_by{ | e | [-e.value, e.page] }
```

if the values have higher priority and are to be sorted in descending order.

Comment: I want value to be in decreasing order, and page to be increasing order.

Comment: If p3, 64 should come after p2,64 and p1 56 should come after p3 56,like [[#<struct Page page="P2", value=64, query="Q1">, #<struct Page page="P3", value=64, query="Q1">, #<struct Page page="P1", value=48, query="Q1">]]

Comment: Typically someone who hasn't argued against this rediculous requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below :

```
s = Struct.new(:page, :value, :query)
a = [["P3", 64,"Q1"],["P2",64,"Q1"],["P1",48,"Q1"]]
a.map!{|i| s.new(*i)}

a.sort_by(&:page).reverse
#>>[#<struct page="P3", value=64, query="Q1">, #<struct page="P2", value=64, query="Q1">, #<struct page="P1", value=48, query="Q1">]
```

*Edit*

Use then the below as you said :

```
a.sort_by{ | e | [-e.value, e.page] }
#=>[#<struct page="P2", value=64, query="Q1">, #<struct page="P3", value=64, query="Q1">, #<struct page="P1", value=48, query="Q1">]
```

Comment: Thanks, But i Want 'P2' to before "P3"

Comment: @prashantsahni depending on what criterion's?